# Ruby wait until external request finished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, watir

I'm using Watir and phantomjs to scrape a page.  I noticed it would throw a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'attributes' for nil:NilClass`
when running it in the console, but if I put a debugger in and stepped through, it would work!  I think the delay in me doing it manually allowed the request to finish.

here's my code:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
browser.goto(map_page_url)
map_page = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html)

#undefined method 'attributes' for nil:NilClass:
coord_url = map_page.at('p:contains("View as") a').attributes['href'].value
```

How can I get it to wait until `browser.goto(map_page_url)` returns fully before moving on?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use nokogiri for this.

```
browser.p(text: /View as/).link.when_present.attribute_value('href')
```